# Checking if a file exists in SVN branch in Java program

Tags: file, svn, branch

I would like to check if a file exist in a SVN branch in java program. Does anyone know how to? I looked for this site but could not find.

Thank.

Comment: A bit more info would help.  Are you looking in a specific branch?  When you say "java program" -- do you mean that the SVN repo has the code for a java program or that you want a java program to search the SVN repo for a file?

Comment: The two easiest ways would be 1) do a Java Runtime.exec() of the SVN command, or 2) do a Java IO.File.exists() on a local copy of your SVN project. You might also be interested in a library, like [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the remote resource for a local resource using the following lines:

```
import org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.ISVNLocalResource;
import org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.ISVNRemoteResource;
...

IResource resource= ....
ISVNLocalResource svnResource = SVNWorkspaceRoot.getSVNResourceFor(resource);
ISVNRemoteResource svnRemoteResource = svnResource.getLatestRemoteResource();
```